# wordpress pagination url first page

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using `paginate_links` on my website.

when i clicked number two url chage as mywebsite.com **/page/2**.
then i cicled pagination page number 1 and site url show mywebsite.com **/page/1**.
i want to remove ***/page/1*** on home page firs page.

this issue only home page.category page are working good.

Ex : `<<prev | 1 | 2 | next >>`

Anyone can help me ?

```
paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_next' => true,
        'prev_text'    => __('Prev Page'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next Page'),
        'type'  => 'array'
    ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a filter for this needs

```
add_filter( 'paginate_links', function($link){

    //Remove link page/1/ from the first element and prev element
    
    if(is_paged()){
        $link= str_replace('page/1/', '', $link);
    }

    return $link;
} );
```

Answer (score -2):

if yoursite.com/page/1 and yoursite.com is the same, why don't you use jquery to change href attribute of your pagination links?

```
$(".pagination a:first").attr("href", "http://example.com/");
```

this code simply changes url of the pagination's first link.

**Edit:** this will change your site's prev link's href attribute. It won't be good if user is on page 3, or whatever.

Try this:

```
if($('.pagination a:first').attr('href') === "http://example.com/page/1") {
    // this is page 2.
    $(".pagination a:first").attr("href", "http://example.com/");
}
    $(".pagination a:nth-child(2)").attr("href", "http://example.com/");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mKBUS/1/)

Comment: yah, i know it can do it also .htaccess file.but i want to know this working on category.php , why its not working on home page.

Thank you for your answer

Comment: You can also use [WP-PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/). It automatically turns `yoursite.com/page/1` to `yoursite.com`.